# Response returns string not dictionairy - TypeError

Tags: python, python-requests

I get a simple API response with an Auth key using Requests, but when I try to grab it using common dict notation, I am told it is a string and I must use INT indicies. I feel like I am missing something obvious but can't figure it out.

```
>>>import requests

>>>r = requests.get(api_url).text

>>>print r

{"PID":"foo","LoginToken":"barbarbarfoofoo","Status":"OK"}

>>>print r['LoginToken']
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

I get the same result using get.content

Answer (score 3):

try

```
requests.get(api_url).json
```

or

```
requests.get(api_url).json()
```

depending on the requests version you have

Comment: Versions where `.json` was a property are quite far in the past now.

Comment: (lol yeah but I just got bit by that ... (yesterday as a matter of fact :P )

Comment: This worked perfectly using json(). What confused me was API documentation said output was string.

Comment: Let me guess: a Ubuntu system where the `requests` library was system installed? Just use a virtualenv and upgrade, 0.8.x is *ancient*.

Comment: @scbro: because you used the `response.text` attribute, which decodes the response as text.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What I mean is the API documentation from the service provider wrote the output would be DataType=String , which is why I didn't think to use Json. Shouldn't they specify it as Json?

Comment: @scbro: Isn't there an overall "API responses" section that explains all responses are JSON encoded an contain a `Status` key? They are probably talking about the `PID` or `LoginToken` parts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Of course, you are right, thanks. They are referring to the individual keys.

Answer (score 0):

The `.text` property of a `requests` response object is text, as the name indicates. If your site is returning a JSON response, you'll need to use something like

```
response = json.loads(r)
```

which will make `response` a dict.

Alternatively,

```
r = requests.get(api_url).json()
```

will make `r` a dict.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely JSON, which has a lot in common with typical Python data structures. If you decode it, you will get a dictionary:

```
import json
json.loads(r)
```

Comment: `requests` gives you a `response.json()` method. It'll use the correct encoding (autodetected if need be).